# localising a text using gettext

Tags: ubuntu, localization, gtk, gnome

I have a text in English which i want to convert it into French.

The sequence that i followed are as under:

1. generate all the text using xgettext command in terminal, creating .pot file
2. creating .po file from .pot file
3. creating .mo file from .po file

I have copy the .mo file in "/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES"

here is my code for main.c file:

```
int main()

{

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    bindtextdomain("main","/usr/share/locale");
    textdomain("main");
    printf( gettext("Hello world\n"));
    return (0);
}
```

When i execute the program the French version of the text is not printed in terminal.
What can be the reason for this issue?

Here is my fr.po file

```
# French translations for GNU main package.
# Copyright (C) 2010 THE GNU main'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the GNU main package.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: GNU main 0.1\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2010-12-29 10:14+0530\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2010-12-29 12:21+0530\n"
"Last-Translator: Lenin\n"
"Language-Team: French\n"
"Language: fr\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ASCII\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"

#: main.c:29
#, c-format
msgid "Hello world\n"
msgstr "Bonjour tout le monde\n"
```

Here is my call to msgfmt from current directory:

```
msgfmt -c -v -o main.mo fr.po
```

Comment: @Martin: Sorry forgot to add question, will edit now.

Comment: Please also show your fr.po, and how you invoke msgfmt.

Comment: @Martin: I have added my fr.po file the command for invoking msgfmt

Comment: @Martin: What happen, please get me out of this issue...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the problem. It works fine for me when I set LANG to fr_FR.UTF-8.

Comment: Does `LC_ALL=fr_FR ./main` work?

Comment: Do other translations (such as `ls --help`) come out correctly?

Comment: @Martin: When i localized into italiano also, gettext is not returning localized string. How could this be solved.

Comment: Please answer the questions above (LC_ALL, ls--help).

Comment: Yes it prints all the information ...

Comment: @Martin: Now it works fine. What i have done is in Language tab i drag french on top. Previous it was not enabled. Sorry i am new to ubuntu...

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to touch the system files/directories.  And you should not touch them if you are developing.

I tried the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <libintl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain("main", ".");
    textdomain("main");
    printf(gettext("Hello world\n"));
    return (0);
}
```

Which is quite similar to your code, except I am testing the localization in my development directory (current one).

Create the template for translations

```
$ xgettext -o main.pot main.c
```

Create the files to translate using the template:

```
$ msginit --no-translator -l es -o es.po -i main.pot
Created es.po.
$ msginit --no-translator -l fr -o fr.po -i main.pot 
Created fr.po.
```

Edit and translate the files.  Set *Project-Id-Version* to *main* and translate the lines.  In this case, the line 23 according to my source code.

Create the target directories for translations:

```
$ mkdir -p es/LC_MESSAGES
$ mkdir -p fr/LC_MESSAGES
```

Compile and install the translations:

```
$ msgfmt -o es/LC_MESSAGES/main.mo es.po 
$ msgfmt -o fr/LC_MESSAGES/main.mo fr.po
```

Compile the program:

```
$ make main
cc     main.c   -o main
```

Run the program:

```
$ LANGUAGE=C ./main 
Hello world
$ LANGUAGE=es ./main
Hola mundo
$ LANGUAGE=fr ./main
Bonjour tout le monde
```

That is.

You might want to compile the program before and fix errors, before translating it.